# How do I use .then() to wait for and use the emitted value of a subscription without using await?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two methods, the first one subscribes to the value of a service which in turn receives a value from a back-end API. I need to make use of this value in a separate method, so therefore I need to wait for the value of the API to be returned by the first method.

The issue is that I don't want to turn the whole method async by using the await keyword, so instead I figured that making the first method return a promise and then using .then() to await the value would work. However when I run my code the console.log is just printing undefined.

```
  async determinePreselectedUsers(googleUsers: GoogleUser[]): Promise<any> {
    let emails: string[] = [];

    googleUsers.forEach(user => {
      emails.push(user.email);
    });

    await this._usersService.determinePreselectedUsers$(emails).subscribe(res => {
      return res;
    });
  }

  onOUSelect(selectedOrganisationalUnitPath: string) {
    this._usersService.getGoogleUsers$(selectedOrganisationalUnitPath).subscribe((googleUsers: GoogleUser[]) => {
       this.determinePreselectedUsers(googleUsers).then( preselectedUsers => {
         console.log("Preselected users: ", preselectedUsers); //This is undefined
       });
    });
  }
```

I assume there's a way to make this work without using await?

Comment: You can't use `async/await` on an observable.You can use something like rxjs mergeMap, switchMap to combine the observables

Comment: @c_ogoo There's only a single observable here, there's nothing to combine it with? All I want to do is funnel the value of an observable through to another method.

Comment: You have to create a higher order observable. The two observables you have to combine are: `this._usersService.getGoogleUsers$` and `this.determinePreselectedUsers` your method `this.determinePreselectedUsers` will return the observable `this._usersService.determinePreselectedUsers$`

Answer (score 2):

This is not the first time I've seen people use async/await on observable and I wonder where the confusion comes from or even if I'm the one being confused here.

Anyway:

There are many things wrong in this single line:

```
await this._usersService.determinePreselectedUsers$(emails).subscribe(res => {
  return res;
});
```

- you are using await with a subscription object
- your observable seems to be a function which has the same name as the function you are calling this with (minus the $)
- your callback in subscribe doesn't do anything.

My guess is that you hope to wait for the subscription to resolve and have the res declared in the scope.

You'd have to do something like this

```
obs1.pipe(
  switchMap(result1 => fetchSomethingElse(result1))
).subscribe(result2 => console.log(result2));
```

Which in your snippet would be:

```
 determinePreselectedUsers(googleUsers: GoogleUser[]): Observable<any> {
    let emails: string[] = [];

    googleUsers.forEach(user => {
      emails.push(user.email);
    });

    return this._usersService.determinePreselectedUsers$(emails); 
  }

  onOUSelect(selectedOrganisationalUnitPath: string) {
    this._usersService.getGoogleUsers$(selectedOrganisationalUnitPath).pipe(
      switchMap(googleUsers: GoogleUser[]) =>   this.determinePreselectedUsers(googleUsers)),
    }).subscribe(preselectedUsers => {
       console.log("Preselected users: ", preselectedUsers); //This is undefined
    });
  }
```

Comment: This makes a lot more sense, thank you. I've just had a thought, since the service is only returning a single value from the API, if I convert the Observable to a promise using asPromise(), would that simplify the whole situation considerably?

Comment: would suggest learning / using observables, rather than converting to promise

Comment: @Jake12342134 you can simplify by putting everything as a promise but I'd advise to pick either one and not mix the two if you are not confortable with the difference yet

Comment: **FYI** this does nothing.... the observable is never subscribed too. If you are coming from *Promises*, then you'll be very confused as to why this doesn't work. Promises will resolve even if `then()` is never called. So it's a good example of why you shouldn't just `toPromise()` instead of learning how observables work.

Comment: @Reactgular edited and put the tap in the subscribe instead for less confusion :/ but Reactgular is right, you should learn this

Comment: @Ced Your code doesn't work, compiler error on `googleUsers` variable

Answer (score 0):

`determinePreselectedUsers` should return value using `resolve` function inside returned `Promise`, not return value directly.

Try this:

```
determinePreselectedUsers(googleUsers: GoogleUser[]): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let emails: string[] = [];

        googleUsers.forEach(user => {
          emails.push(user.email);
        });

        this._usersService.determinePreselectedUsers$(emails).subscribe(
            // return response in then using resolve
            resolve,
            // return error in catch using reject
            reject
        );
    });
}
```

or, You can use `toPromise` function of Observable, like:

```
determinePreselectedUsers(googleUsers: GoogleUser[]): Promise<any> {

    let emails: string[] = [];

    googleUsers.forEach(user => {
            emails.push(user.email);
    });

    return this._usersService.determinePreselectedUsers$(emails).toPromise();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your source code to fewer lines using a [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html) operator and [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html) to switch to another observable. The key benefit of using Rxjs is that it allows us to write [declaratively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming) what the logic does. Promises are perfectly fine to use, but they describe the resolving of data while reactive programming describes how data flows.

```js
function onOUSelect(selectedOrganisationalUnitPath: string) {
    const pluckEmails = users => [users, users.map(user => user.email)];
    const handleEmails = ([users, emails]) => this._usersService.determinePreselectedUsers$(users, emails);

    this._usersService.getGoogleUsers$(selectedOrganisationalUnitPath).pipe(
        map(pluckEmails),
        switchMap(handleEmails)
    ).subscribe(values => console.log(values)); // you must subscribe!
}
```

The use of `async/wait` has some known side effects including error handling, difficulties with concurrency and the fact that it is syntax sugar for writing promises. When you use `toPromise()` with an observable you inherently change the behavior of how an observable handles errors and empty states. There are times when you need to use it, but falling back to `toPromise()` so you can continue to work with promises is an anti-pattern in Angular.

Observables are the first thing you need to learn in Angular, and the only thing you'll never finish learning.

Comment: This is a much simpler option, thank you. Is there also a way for me to be able to access the original googleUsers object from the first observable too? I need both.

Comment: @Jake12342134 I updated my answer so that the googleUsers variable and the emails are both forwarded to the `handleEmails`.

Comment: Ah I apologise, I must not have been clear. I was asking if there is a way to access both variables within the subscribe? So having references to `users` and `values`. However I imagine since the single combined subscription can only have a single emission that this is not possible?

Answer (score -1):

Below should work

```
determinePreselectedUsers(googleUsers: GoogleUser[]): Observable<any> {
    let emails: string[] = [];

    googleUsers.forEach(user => {
      emails.push(user.email);
    });

    return this._usersService.determinePreselectedUsers$(emails);
  }

  onOUSelect(selectedOrganisationalUnitPath: string) {
    this._usersService.getGoogleUsers$(selectedOrganisationalUnitPath).subscribe((googleUsers: GoogleUser[]) => {
       this.determinePreselectedUsers(googleUsers).then( preselectedUsers => {
         console.log("Preselected users: ", preselectedUsers); //This is undefined
       });
    });
  }
```